# Recently Opened Apps

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there any way of getting a list of, say 4, recently opened Applications? If so, how?

(Cocoa Mac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `LaunchServices/LSSharedFileList.h` header file. Unfortunately, the functions in this file are not documented in the Xcode docs, but the comments in the file are very good. Basically, you create a reference to the list of recently opened applications by passing `kLSSharedFileListRecentApplicationItems` to `LSSharedFileListCreate()`. Then get an array of the current contents of the list with `LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot()`.

Comment: Hmm, ok! Thanks for that answer! I started with this code...

Comment: applist1 = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListRecentApplicationItems, NULL);
          
 UInt32 seed;
 applistArray = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(applist1, &seed);
 
 NSLog(@"ARRAY: %@",[applistArray description]);

Comment: What gets logged is a list of items like "<LSSharedFileListItem(44) of 0x100437910> 0x1 Spotify"

Comment: How do I extract "Spotify" from that?

Comment: I don't know how to extract the name of the Item :S any hints? http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Ok, now I got it, you should be using `LSSharedFileListItemCopyDisplayName`